# I creating a receipt generator in python and I fetch data from MySQL to a text area but it's not work. I don't know that where I making the mistake

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*

from PIL import Image,ImageTk

from tkinter import ttk

import mysql.connector

from tkinter import messagebox

import time

root=Tk()

root.title("Hotel Management System")

root.geometry("1135x470+225+221")

#====================== Variables ======================
        
var_id=StringVar()

#=====================Function for receipt and Fetch data from mysql ========================

def receipt():


 if var_id.get()=="":

  messagebox.showerror("Error","Please Enter Customer ID",parent=root)

 else:

  conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",username="root",password="sqlab12",database="management")

  my_cursor=conn.cursor()

  query=("select Ref from customer where Idnumber=%s")

  value=(var_id.get(),)

  my_cursor.execute(query,value)

  row=my_cursor.fetchone()



 if row==None:

  messagebox.showerror("Error","This Number is Not Found",parent=root)

 else:

  conn.commit()

  conn.close()

  date=time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

  textarea.insert(END,"Customer Ref:"+row+date)

    


#====================== Title =======================
 
lbl_title=Label(root,text="BILL GENERATE ",font=("time new 
roman",18,"bold"),bg="black",fg="gold",bd=4,relief=RIDGE)

lbl_title.place(x=0,y=0,width=1135,height=50)

#========================== LOGO =====================

img2=Image.open(r"F:\Pictures\VA\Project\Hotel Management System\images\logohotel.png")

img2=img2.resize((100,40),Image.ANTIALIAS)

photoimg2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)

lblimg=Label(root,image=photoimg2,bd=0,relief=RIDGE)

lblimg.place(x=5,y=5,width=100,height=40)

#============================================== RECEIPT =================

F2=Frame(root,relief=GROOVE,bd=5)

F2.place(x=580,y=90,width=530,height=380)

bill_title=Label(root,text="Receipt",font=("arial",15,"bold"),bd=7,relief=GROOVE)

bill_title.place(x=580,y=50,width=530)

scrol=Scrollbar(F2,orient=VERTICAL)      

scrol.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

textarea=Text(F2,font=("arial",12,"bold"),yscrollcommand=scrol.set) 

textarea.pack(fill=BOTH)

scrol.config(command=textarea.yview)


#============================================== BUTTONS ============================

btn_frame=Frame(root,bd=3,relief=RIDGE)

btn_frame.place(x=6,y=346,width=417,height=42)


#=====================CUSTOMER_ID_NUMBER=================

lbl_cust_id=Label(root,text="Customer ID :",font=("arial",13,"bold"),padx=5,pady=4)

lbl_cust_id.place(x=6,y=250)

enty_id=ttk.Entry(root,width=23,textvariable=var_id,font=("arial",13,"bold"))

enty_id.place(x=140,y=250)

btnReceipt=Button(btn_frame,text="Receipt",command=receipt,font=("arial",11,"bold"),bg="black",fg="gold",width=10)

btnReceipt.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=2,pady=2)

btnPrint=Button(btn_frame,text="Print",font=("arial",11,"bold"),bg="black",fg="gold",width=10)

btnPrint.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=1,pady=2)

btnSave=Button(btn_frame,text="Save",font=("arial",11,"bold"),bg="black",fg="gold",width=10)

btnSave.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=1,pady=2)

btnSend=Button(btn_frame,text="Send",font=("arial",11,"bold"),bg="black",fg="gold",width=10)

btnSend.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=1,pady=2)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does it mean, "not working"! you have to be more specific

Comment: Could you please try to condense the code down to a [mcve]. There seems to be some code that isn't strictly necessary to reproduce the problem. For example, we don't need the images or all of the blank lines, or some of the buttons.

Comment: Since `row` is a tuple (result of `fetchone()`), the line `textarea.insert(END,"Customer Ref:"+row+date)` will raise exception because you cannot concatenate str with tuple.  change `row` to `row[0]`.

Comment: Now it's work, I change textarea.insert(END,"Customer Ref:"+row+date)                           
to                                                                                             textarea.insert(END,"Customer Ref:{row}"+date)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something to insert in place of the %s:

```
query=("select Ref from customer where Idnumber=%s")
```

needs to have something like

```
query=("select Ref from customer where Idnumber=%s" % Idnumber)
```